# Calling object elements as a variable to modify value

Tags: python, class

I have a class I've established to store a variety of values.

```
class character:
    #basic skills
    Name= ""
    stat1 = 0
    stat2 = 0
    stat3 = 0
```

The plan is to let the user decide which elements of an object it assigns different values to:

```
#create the pc based on character class
pc = character()
pc.Name = input ("Enter your characters name now: ")
attribute = ["stat1", "stat2", "stat3"]
choice = input("Using the numbers below, which of these stats do you want your character to be exceptional at? Or pick 0 to restart from picking a name:")
if choice == "0":
    welcome()
try:
    choice = int(choice)
    print ("You have selected " + attribute[choice-1] + " to be your strongest stat.")
    #stat alocation broken, doesnt update stat
    stat = attribute[choice-1]
    pc.stat = 4
    #removes that stat as a choice
    attribute.pop(choice-1)
except:
    print("I'm sorry, we cant understand what you have chosen, please try again.")
    pc = statgen(pc)
print("Heres your sheet so far:")
    print ("Name: ", pc.Name, "\nStat1: ", pc.stat1, "\nstat2: ", pc.stat2, "\nstat3: ", pc.stat3)
```

Now, when I run the script and put myself through to the end it still posts all the stats as 0 despite the fact it should've assigned the value chosen to 4. Other stats also get assigned the value of 3 and 2 in the same manner the 4 stat is selected.

output is the following:

```
Heres your sheet so far:
Name:  Dan 
stat1:  0
stat2:  0
stat3:  0
```

Not really sure why it isn't assigning the values to the int elements while allowing the string value for name. If anyone can see why this is the case I would very much appreciate the assistance.

Comment: because you are assigning to `pc.stat`, just because `stat` is some variable that refers to a `str` object won't make Python *interpolate that string into your source code*. Strings *are not source code*.

Comment: Now, there are ways to use a string to dynamically get/set/delete an attribute, notably, with `getattr`/`setattr` built-in functions (see the linked dupliate). But it is crucial to understand what I am trying to expressive above - *strings are not source code*.

Comment: `pc.stat` should be a list of 3 elements.  Now you can refer to `pc.stat[choice]` and everybody is happy.